# Your site is unable to reach WordPress.org at api.wordpress.org

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, centos

I installed Centos 7 + nginx + php 8.1 + mariadb + Wordpress.

There is no access to external connections in Wordpress.
For example, I don't have access to the Wordpress plugin library

An error occurs: "Your site is unable to reach WordPress.org at api.wordpress.org, and returned the error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.wordpress.org; Unknown error"

But I checked Сurl in Сentos and it works. (like curl https://google.com)

[root@ ~]# curl https://www.google.com

<!doctype html><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="des..............

I also tried to change the "hosts" file and DNS settings in "resolve.conf". But it didn't help.

What could be the problem? As far as I understand, the problem is on the nginx side?

Comment: I suppose you use `php-fpm`, so it is actually php curl module makes this request. Have you tried to check if php is able to resolv `api.wordpress.org`? `<?php $ip = gethostbyname('api.wordpress.org'); var_dump($ip);?>`

Comment: @user973254
 yes i have php-fpm. it says: string(17) "api.wordpress.org"

Comment: then it's not `php` or `nginx` problem, you should dig your php scripts logic

Answer (score 0):

Giving up on the security essential that makes Community **Enterprise** OS what it is, by disabling it, is never a solution.

The right way to allow web server processes to connect to external resources is an SELinux boolean switch:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with SELinux. I turned it off and everything worked.